# How did Chinese Parsley get its name?

Tags: etymology, history

What is the history behind the names " Chinese Parsley" and "Cilantro"?

Comment: This might be better for the English language community. Unless of course someone here knows! Then you came to the right spot :)

Comment: Coriander is native to Asia, and, as everyone in Europe knew way back when, that meant China.  "Cilantro" is derived from the Spanish word for "coriander".

Comment: Sorry, I aside this was migrated from Cooking.SE, but it's not a good fit here either. If the question is purely etymological, then it can be answered by a dictionary, and so is off-topic as "general reference". If the answer is historical and cultural, then it can't be answered by experts in *English* (and I would assume Cooking.se would have been the best place to ask).

Comment: @DanBron I have to correct you here. Cooking.se is not "anything about food" and we do not have the expertise to discuss cultural and historical aspects of food or eating. We are focused on cooking only, this means food preparation. If you think that this question is out of place here as a language question, you can vote to close, which will simply result it in being closed on both sites.

Comment: @Hot Licks: in my experience, coriander is much more common in Indian cuisine than in Chinese cuisine. And in fact, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriander) says it's native to southwestern Asia and southern Europe. I would guess it's called *Chinese parsley* because the English in the Middle Ages didn't differentiate very well between India and China.

Comment: @rumtscho That's why I said "I assume this was migrated from Cooking" and "I assume Cooking *would have been* the best", as in, that was my expectation, but the very fact that it was migrated here indicates that expectation was invalid. I was not suggesting migrating it back.

Comment: @PeterShor That's what HL presumably meant by "it came from Asia [which includes India], and as everyone in Europe knew way back when, Asia == China" (ie he was being sarcastic, but saying the same thing you are).

Comment: OK, I felt it necessary to leave the comment because the idea that "cooking is a good place for such question" arises a lot in the network, so pointing out that this is not so in places like this is helpful for Cooking.se in general, no matter what happens to this one question.

Comment: Our speculations seem wrong. The name "Chinese parsley" seems to have originated in the U.S. in the late 19th century, when Americans may have first encountered it in Chinese restaurants.

Comment: It's called variously, using *parsley* as the similar-looking plant that Europeans were used to: both *chinese parsley* and *mexican parsley* have been used (there have long been Chinese and Mexican communities in the US). And in the US, since curly-leaf parsley was the best known for quite a while (it was used mainly as a decoration), the flat-leaf parsley used widely in european cooking is sometimes known in the US as *italian parsley*. If a group of people were known to use a given vegetable then their group name was sometimes taken to qualify the name of the more familiar vegetable.

Answer (score 3):

The term *Chinese parsley* appears to have originated in the United States near New York City in the late 19th century. The OED's first citation is from the *New York Times* in 1895, although Google books finds an [1893](https://books.google.com/books?id=nfIJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA491&dq=%22chinese+parsley%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv_bWtufbQAhWlLcAKHWLEDFQQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=1893&f=false) reference, discussing the same Chinese-American farms mentioned below.

[This 1899 Google books reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=iQtIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA390-IA6&dq=%22chinese+parsley%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_q6qAtPbQAhWFJMAKHWTjCAQQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22chinese%20parsley%22&f=false) explains how Hen Shang started a farm in Astoria (in Queens, NYC) around 1880, where he grew Chinese vegetables. After he proved successful, he was joined in partnership by some other Chinese immigrants, and several others started their own farms. One of the crops mentioned was *Chinese parsley*. Other crops were *yun tsoi*, *bok tsoi*, and *Chinese eggplant*.

So it seems probable that many New Yorker's first exposure to cilantro came from the cilantro grown on these Chinese farms in Astoria. It looks something like parsley; hence the name.

The names *[coriander](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=coriander)* and *[cilantro](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cilantro)* are both ultimately derived from the Latin word *coriandrum*, which in turn comes from ancient Greek name for the herb, *κορίαννον* ‎(*koríannon*), coming through French and Spanish, respectively.

Comment: Wait, Chinese eggplant? Wuzzat? The Chinese call tomatoes ‘Western eggplants’, but I'm assuming Chinese eggplants probably aren't tomatoes…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet:  "Chinese eggplant" are a variety of eggplant that is longer and thinner than the usual "Western" eggplant.  They also tend to have fewer seeds, thinner skins, and a milder flavour.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert So presumably just what the Chinese would call eggplant, then? Never knew there was a difference!

Comment: @Janus: the 1893 article also mentions "Chinese pumpkins". I have no idea what these are. But searching in Google books, this seems to be some kind of squash with green rind and white flesh.

Comment: @PeterShor At least it's not Chinese watermelon. That would be a proper catch-22: the Chinese for ‘watermelon’ is ‘Western melon’! (Unlike pumpkins, which are ‘southern melons’.)